# Apache reverse proxying distorts assets paths

Tags: apache, redirect, configuration, assets, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure a reverse proxy from Apache web server (A) to another Apache web server on different machine (B).

I could manage to access web page located on server B as if it were on server A, but all assets' paths (images, CSSs, JSs etc) were distorted.

I used below configuration on server A:

```
ProxyPass "/app1/" "http://some.host.address:8080/app1/"
ProxyPassReverse "/app1/" "some.host.address:8080/app1/"
ProxyHTMLURLMap "http://some.host.address:8080" "/app1"

<Location /app1/>
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app1/
</Location>
```

Comment: And "all assets' paths were distorted" means what _exactly_? How did they look?

Comment: By saying "distorted" I meant that browser was not able to access them. Maybe word inaccessible would suite better to describe my problem.Sorry confusion)

Comment: Ok, so much was clear from your description. But the question still remains: how do the links look like?

Comment: @arkascha sorry, it seems that I had completely wrong idea of what was happening with asset. Their paths were not distorted, there was a problem with decoding them - ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED.
For this I have raised yet another topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683850/apache-proxying-leads-to-err-content-decoding-failed-error

Please kindly take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is your backend application is generating links with "some.host.address" instead of the public url you are requesting, because your application generates not relative links but also includes hostname.

Use:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
```

and try again. This will send the same hostname the client has requested to the backend, and then your backend application will use the name you want.

Comment: I have this in my configuration. Anyway the problem I face is not related to assets' paths distortion. There is ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error occurring all the time to some assets.
Please kindly take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683850/apache-proxying-leads-to-err-content-decoding-failed-error