# Apache Proxying leads to ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error

Tags: apache, configuration, assets, reverse-proxy, decoding

I'm trying to configure a reverse proxy from Apache web server (A) to another Apache web server on different machine (B).

With configuration I'm currently using I'm able to access web page located on server B as if it were on server A, however requests for some assets constantly result in **ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED** (at least in chrome).
This doesn't happen when I'm using simple redirection instead of proxying.

I have browsed through request and response headers and it seems that everything went fine with file transferring:

Request:

```
GET /app1/assets/css/vendor.min.css?1470017050 HTTP/1.1
Host: some.host.address
...
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I used below configuration on server A:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass "/app1/" "http://some.host.address:8080/app1/"
ProxyPassReverse "/app1/" "some.host.address:8080/app1/"
ProxyHTMLURLMap "http://some.host.address:8080" "/app1"

<Location /app1/>
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app1/
</Location>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error occurs when the back-end server uses compression and the proxy server doesn't handle deflated content during rewriting.

I found useful information in [this wiki](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php?title=Reverse_Proxy_Server_2:_mod_proxy_html_2#Cause_and_Solution_3) and also in the [mod_proxy_html documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html).

I tried the following with success (inflate before rewriting):

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app1/
```

Then after reading a (now removed) comment on the mod_proxy_html page, I modified to this (should handle character encoding correctly):

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
ProxyHTMLCharsetOut *
ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app1/
ProxyHTMLURLMap /app1/ /app1/
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding `SetOutputFilter` did it. The comment you reference is gone though.

Comment: `ProxyHTMLEnable On
RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
ProxyHTMLCharsetOut *` help me to remove those Â encoding issue

Comment: Thanks, using just the second part (addition of `RequestHeader` and `ProxyHTMLCharsetOut`) worked for me, didn't need the `SetOutputFilter`.